# Storing/Securing sensitive information in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have created an app where I am giving reward points to user based on some tasks. Depending on whether the task is completed or not, I am increasing reward points of the user. The user details along with the reward points is stored in Firebase. How can I set security rules so that users cannot modify the reward points themselves? I want to increase the reward points as soon as the user completes the task. So, I cannot afford to manually open the console and increase the reward points myself.

PS - I am just starting with Firebase Security Rules.

Comment: Short answer: it depends.  How are you tracking if the task is completed?  How are you updating the database?  Obviously having `write` set to true in the rules is bad, but past that it depends on how your app actually works

Comment: I have status codes which informs me whether the task is completed or not. So, if the status code is true, I am doing an update on the reward points field in the database and increasing the reward points.

Comment: If you have no secure backend code that can bypass security rules and perform the update, then you're going to have a very hard time with this, since your rules are going to have to reject all writes coming directly from the client.